# KTA update document and visualization

Tags: kofax

I developped an application that can retrieve a file from KTA and send it back.
For this I used 4 entry points :

1. LogOnWithPassword2 (allow to log on to KTA),
2. GetSourceFile (I retrieve a file encoded in byte array),
3. UpdateSourceFile( once my file modified, i return it in byte array onto KTA and update it...)
4. Log off the application.

So far, so good, everything is working fine. In order to check if the process is working, I run a second time my application and I do retrieve the document I sent to KTA.

For retrieving the document, I use the document Id that is provided by KTA. In this case the application is running correctly.

I return a simple PDF with an inspired "Hello World". My issue is the following : when I try to visualize the updated document in KTA i just have the initial document. It means that i don't visualize the update. Here is a capture of several screens from KTA. Instead of this document.

Is there a configuration issue in KTA ? Here is my actual BPMN screenshot. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In KTA the source file is separate from the page objects, which is touched on in this [KB article](https://knowledge.kofax.com/Smart_Process_Applications/ScriptingProgramming/Why_might_requesting_a_PDF_from_the_CaptureDocumentService.GetDocumentFile_API_return_an_unexpected_result%3F) (may require login), and interactive activities will always display TIFFs, not source files.  This is why you do not see the changes from your updated source file.

Your “Crea TIFF” activity is probably an Image Processing activity, which creates page objects (which are always TIFF) from any non-TIFF source file that has been imported.  Note that if TIFFs are imported directly, then they should directly become page objects and the document should have no source file.

**Option 1 - Recreate pages from modified source file**
After you’ve changed the source file but before Validation, you could probably call [DeletePages](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.7.0-o3xtk9orwd/help/API/latest/class_agility_1_1_sdk_1_1_services_1_1_capture_document_service.html#a583576e2e0275a685dd31482021208b9), then send the document through a second Image Processing activity.  I would expect that this should then recreate the page objects from your updated source file.

**Option 2 - Modify pages directly**
Instead of (or in addition to) updating the source file, you could update the pages directly.  I believe this would still mean calling DeletePages, and then using [CreatePage](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.7.0-o3xtk9orwd/help/API/latest/class_agility_1_1_sdk_1_1_services_1_1_capture_document_service.html#a2e132f48c8522ea1d835cd8c603b3181) or [CreatePageUsingStream](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.7.0-o3xtk9orwd/help/API/latest/class_agility_1_1_sdk_1_1_services_1_1_capture_document_service.html#a182446c09fbcffa6e1225c251e3d5e0b).  But before that in terms of getting the TIFF data, you would have to decide whether you are converting your modified source file to TIFF yourself, or if you are getting the pages from KTA as TIFF using [GetPageImage](https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.7.0-o3xtk9orwd/help/API/latest/class_agility_1_1_sdk_1_1_services_1_1_capture_document_service.html#ab87798168493a2e3757c4101a8c95895), and then modifying those directly.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answear ! I'm going to try using the rest entry points.